# Bootstrap 4. Странная валидация

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Столкнулся с этим при верстке формы.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg is_invalid">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg is_valid">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg is-valid">
  <span class="invalid-feedback">Doesnt work</span>  
</div>
```

Первые две строки "нерабочие", то есть валидация на них не работает, а вот две нижние спокойно ее обрабатывают. Так и не понял в чем причина. Если копипастить "работающий" и "неработающий" код, то они соответственно работают и не работают. Не знаю как это можно нормально описать. Впервые сталкиваюсь с подобным.

https://jsfiddle.net/y6beng2k/

Comment: Название классов разные вместо `_` надо `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Но ведь в первых двух строках стоит "_" вместо "-". Соответственно стиля для "is_invalid" нет, а для "is-invalid" - есть =)

Comment: Блин, спасибо вам большое! Вот это я невнимательный(